# SQL Server: Query for fetch odd and even rows from the table for InTime and Out Time

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table Name: Employee

```
Id                                     EmployeeName  FingerId
8b6c653e-6b20-46f2-89a1-45ed3b453345     xyz           19
8b6c653e-6b20-46f2-89a1-45ed3b453876     abc           17
```

Table Name: INOUT

```
 No   AutoId                                   Fingerid       LogTime             Date
 1  8b6c653e-6b20-46f2-89a1-45ed3b45369c       19           10:43:36 AM        7/27/2011 
 2  b4246d49-df99-4355-9327-4703a7642b32       19           10:45:00 AM        7/27/2011 
 3  274e64e4-e95b-4a1c-815c-9aee9c2d3ac8       19           11:30:20 AM        7/27/2011 
 4  f7197cb8-3a76-4c75-b801-9df545ff67b1       19           12:30:00 PM    7/27/2011 
 5  43230f6d-6872-4ce4-8f3a-ceb74d757722       19           12:30:55 PM    7/27/2011
```

I want a stored procedure for this table (`INOUT`) in which it have `Fingerid` of particular employee, `LogTime` of particular finger and date

Here in above table have `Fingerid` 19 of 5 entries of same date 7/27/2011

I want the query which is group by date and sort by time with seconds and

- 1 record IN TIME and 2 record OUT TIME
- 3 record IN TIME and 4 record OUT TIME

like odd should be IN TIME and even should be OUT TIME

And also Time difference between In Time and out time

Output I want:

```
EmployeeName    InTime          OutTime          Date            DifferenceTimeperiod
  XYZ          10:43:00 AM      10:45:00 AM     7/27/2011        00:2:00 mints
```

Comment: Employee "xyz" has "FingerId = 22" in your first table - but it seems to select the data for "FingerId = 19" from your second table..... and how do you differentiate IN and OUT from your second table? Just "odd" and "even" row "index" seems like a very weak and unsafe method.... Not clear at all ....

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the seconds part. What do we do with two measurements inside the same minute? Also, what appears on the 3rd row of your output (for input line 5)? Do you really not measure/record anything objective that establishes whether each row in INOUT represents an in time or an out time?

Comment: Difference IN and OUT form 2nd table it should form "LogTime" odd record will be IN TIME and even record will be OUT TIME. which will be group by date and sort by Time

Comment: Why don't you just store it as [InTime] [OutTime]...?

Comment: I have only one field "Log Time" in that number of record of particular employee for particular date. Employee will IN and OUT number of time in a day so how system will identify that IN Time and Out Time. So their is one field "LOG TIME"

Comment: SELECT t.Fingerid, t.LogTime, t.[Date]
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Fingerid) AS RowNumber 
            --Row_Number() starts with 1
    FROM InOut
) t
WHERE t.RowNumber % 2 = 1 and t.Fingerid = 19
 
 
 
SELECT t.Fingerid, t.LogTime, t.[Date]
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Fingerid) AS RowNumber 
            --Row_Number() starts with 1
    FROM InOut
) t
WHERE t.RowNumber % 2 = 0 and t.Fingerid = 19                                                                   i got odd and even record by query but other thing remains

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this, with alarm logs:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AlarmLogs([TimeStamp] datetime, Incoming bit, AlarmID int)
```

This had entries with an incoming and phasing out (1,0) so I knew when the alarm was turning on or off.  However, sometimes there would be several incoming signals before a phasing out, i.e.

```
2011/01/01 13:55:43, 1, 246
2011/01/01 13:55:48, 1, 246
2011/01/01 13:56:14, 0, 246
2011/01/01 13:57:38, 1, 246
2011/01/01 13:58:16, 0, 246
```

I spent a long time trying to solve this with various SQL techniques, including self joins etc, but have now solved it with a cursor.

Although cursor use should be minimised, there are times when they actually perform faster, and this was one of them.

The cursor simply looped through the sorted table, and inserted the alarm to a results table once it found the end time.

Hope that helps.